# Обработка видео после загрузки на сервер Django

Tags: python, django

Так как поиск мне не очень помог обращаюсь к вам. У меня существует небольшой проэкт на Джанго и не очень уж хочу писать огромный велосипед.
В общем вся суть такова. Мне нужно после загрузки пользователем видеофайла переконвертировать файл в webp например а так же сделать превью. В общем по типу загрузки видео в YouTube или вконтакте.
Понимаю что этим будет заниматься ffmpeg и по этому нужна хоть примерная реализация.
Прошу сильно не пинать и дать хоть вектор правильного направления в кокую сторону капать.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: На английском просто гуглится `ffmpeg convert to webp`, например: https://gist.github.com/witmin/1edf926c2886d5c8d9b264d70baf7379

Comment: Не как пользоваться ffmpeg я знаю. Мне просто нужно хоть примерно знать как реализовать загрузку и конвертирование чтоб пользователь это видел, по типу как на YouTube сделано.

Comment: Мб есть и готовое решение... Но если бы руками делать, то можно было через веб-сокеты из сервера отправлять прогресс обработки, либо сделать через ajax, но тогда с стороны клиента нужно было отправлять запросы на сервер и запрашивать прогресс (в этом случае можно были или в памяти хранить прогресс или в каком-то хранилище, типа базы данных). Нашел пример отображения прогресса при работе ffmpeg: https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/blob/df129c7ba30aaa9ffffb81a48f53aa7253b0b4e6/examples/show_progress.py

Comment: Я тут подумал что это можно реализовать через метод перед сохранением и отображать модальном окне. Точнее их три 1 это выбор файла, 2 загрузка, 3 обработка с заполнением данных. По реализации я посмотрю. И всё таки важен пример, хоть я и буду всё реализовывать своими силами.